# How to get the MyfirebaseMessanginService alive when user killed his/her app. in android?

Tags: android, firebase

Explanation:

Yesterday, i integrated a firebase push notification in my project.I have got Notification when i was sending it from the firebase messaging dashboard to the particular device or a device which installed my application.It was working successfully. Firebase allows you to get the message in two different format one is using payload it means sent by the firebase dashboard and another send by the user from the particular server data message.I have achieved both of this two even my application is in foreground/Backgrouond or killed by the user manually. When i sent it.My application appear notification pop-up on to of my device with required data i needed.

There is one service namely MyFirebaseMessagingSerive which listen a message and push this message to the device. When my application is in foreground it's this service is alive and when i put the debug pointer inside this service it call that debug But, when i kill my application and send a message i received a notification pop-up on the device but my service is not alive. There are few task of navigation i have performed inside this service to navigate the user according to the data which i have received on the notification data in JSON format.

Take an example, of hotstar application. When two matches happen at the same time. ind vs wi and sa vs aus. When match start b/w ind vs wi i get an notification independently. same for the sa vs aus i get new notification independently. When i click on the ind vs wi notification i redirected the particular ind vs wi live match screen. When i click on the sa vs aus i am redirected to the sa vs aus live match screen. I want to achieve this functionality in my application. This is the just an example given to you for better understanding to solve this issue.

My requirement is whether i am in foreground or background or kill the application. How can i achieve to manage this service alive specifically in kill the application.

Comment: did you try to send your notifications as `data message` ?

Answer (score 0):

According to documents if you send your notification via the firebase console or `notification message` if the app is foreground the `onMessageReceived` method will invoke and if the app is backgrounded the notification delivers to device's system tray. So to fix this issue you should try to send some JSON like this to Firebase console URL:

```
{
"to" : “/topics/global“,
"data" : {
“key-1" : “value-1“,
“key-2" : “value-2“,
“key-3" : “value-3"
}
}
```

and even if the application is foregrounded or backgrounded the `onMessageReceived` method will invoke.

Here is a complete [article](https://medium.com/@shayan.ta69/how-to-handle-fcm-notification-in-backgrounded-android-applications-29229c4f9975) on medium, and this is the [example](https://github.com/shayantabatabaee/Espionage) of a project to control android device remotely with Firebase notifications.